# Get the last created symlink file in a directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, symlink

I have a directory of sym link files shown below.

How can i get the last created file from the directory

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 cha mux 46 Apr 30 03:39 load-16.29-40 -> ../../../build-150429/swp/latest/load-16.29-40
lrwxrwxrwx 1 cha mux 46 Apr 30 21:36 load-16.30-40 -> ../../../build-150430/swp/latest/load-16.30-40
lrwxrwxrwx 1 cha mux 45 May  3 22:58 load-17.2-40 -> ../../../build-150502/swp/latest/load-17.2-40
lrwxrwxrwx 1 cha mux 45 May  5 01:39 load-17.4-40 -> ../../../build-150504/swp/latest/load-17.4-40
lrwxrwxrwx 1 cha mux 45 May  6 00:58 load-17.5-40 -> ../../../build-150505/swp/latest/load-17.5-40
lrwxrwxrwx 1 cha mux 45 May  7 03:19 load-17.6-10 -> ../../../build-150506/swp/latest/load-17.6-10
```

The output should be "load-17.6-10"

Answer (score 0):

This is the file list:

```
os.listdir(dir)
```

Just symbolic links:

```
[name for name in os.listdir(dir) if os.path.islink(name)]
```

Latest link:

```
max([name for name in os.listdir(dir) if os.path.islink(name)],
    key = lambda f: os.lstat(os.path.join(dir, f)).st_ctime)
```

Here using [`os.lstat()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.lstat): it works just like `os.stat()` but doesn't follow symlinks.